# Data Split Strategy

Tags: neural-networks, validation, hyperparameter, train-test-split

In case of very less data set for training and testing, can I remove validation set and keep only train and test set for training a DL network for segmentation? If yes, then how to get the best model for testing as usually we choose model which performs best on validation set?

Comment: You’re doing deep learning with $100$ points?

Comment: Yes, it's a 3d volumetric image data and each volume contains around 14 slices. So indirectly it contains around 1400 2d image slices.

Comment: But do those 14 slices all correspond to the same output point?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.